# C#: How to fill data to DataGridView through WCF Service?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, datagridview

So I'm trying to take the data from the Database into my `DataGridView` (which is `movieGridView` in my case) inside the client side application when the form is loaded.
I've tried this before:

Code from WCF `Service.cs`:

```
public DataSet getMovieData()
{
    sqlcon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_movie", sqlcon);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlcon.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Code from WCF `IService.cs`:

```
[OperationContract]
DataSet getMovieData();
```

Code at client side application:

```
    private void DeleteMovie_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = obj.getMovieData();
        movieGridView.DataSource = ds;
    }
```

That `[OperationContract]` is already inside the `[ServiceContract]` of course. The form is loaded with no error whatsoever, and take some time to load (maybe it's trying to take the data from the Database),  but the `DataGridView` shows nothing, it's blank. And no, the table name is not wrong, the connection code is also fine because I've tried to login and success. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery(); ?

Also try adding sqlcom.CommandType.Text

Comment: Just tried that, not working, still blank. Any suggestion?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856252/datagridview-not-showing-columns-data[/link]

Comment: Wow that works! I need to change `movieGridView.DataSource = ds;` to `movieGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to bind the data in the gridview

```
movieGridView.DataSource = ds;
movieGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: There's no DataBind() method in WindowsForm application :( That's only available in Web application...

Comment: oh sorry ! i thought that it's a web application.